# Hamburger menu from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I need help with my code for a hamburger menu. I need to use this array to create the menu elements in jquery:

```
var menu = [{
  'title': 'Save',
  'onclick': function() {
    alert('Open clicked');
  }
}, {
  'title': 'Load',
  'onclick': function() {
    alert('Close clicked');
  }
}, {
  'title': 'Hide menu',
  'onclick': function() {
    //put a code to close menu
  }
}];
```

Here is what I have so far and I need to use the array above to update it to work with the array.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#menulink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('.navigation-wrapper').hasClass('show-menu')) {
        $('.navigation-wrapper').removeClass('show-menu');
        $('.navigation').hide();
        $('.navigation li').removeClass('small-padding');
    } else {
        $('.navigation-wrapper').addClass('show-menu');
        $('.navigation').fadeIn();
        $('.navigation li').addClass('small-padding');
   }
});

  });
```

HTML

```
<a id="menulink" href="#">
    <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
     <div class="inner-hamburger-wrapper">
          <div class="hamburger"></div>
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-title"><p>Menu</p></div>
</div>
</a>
```

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
```

It would be nice to get any help that I can.

Comment: please ask something definite, your question is too open

Comment: can you post a fiddle out of this? I don't see you using `menu` anywhere?

Comment: I think they are asking how to take an anonymous type array and turn it into an `UL`

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle for my code: https://jsfiddle.net/egbgqdo3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jQuery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) you can append the array items to a list for creation.

We have to target the functions seperately, but included is a solution where you could put them inline, if you converted the `menu[i]` items to strings.

```
  // Generate an element, append index to referencing the executing function
  $.each(menu, function(index, element) {
    $('ul.navigation').append('<li data-index="'+index+'"><a href="#">'+element.title+'</a></li>');
  });

  // Run the executing function associated with item
  $('ul.navigation > li').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('data-index');
    menu[item].onclick();
  });

  // This could be done easier like so:
  //  $.each(menu, function(index, element) {
  //    $('ul.navigation').append('<li data-index="'+index+'"><a href="#" onclick="'+element.onclick+'">'+element.title+'</a></li>');
  // });
  // but would require modifying the menu[i] items' functions to just be strings
```

[Here's an updated Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnstrickland/egbgqdo3/2/)

Comment: Thank you! Now how would I go about hiding the menu if I were to push the hide menu button

Comment: Just apply the same classes you did to show it.  I've updated the fiddle to include the hiding logic. If you find my answer helpful, please mark it accordingly. You can play with animation here as well, just keep in mind that a `fadeOut()` will not finish firing by the time you hide the black background (you'll need `setTimeout()` or something similar for that).